# number e is less or equal to 1/i!

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone help me with the proof of this exercise:

> $$\binom{n}{i} n^{-i} \le \frac{1}{i!}$$

This is a part of another exercise, and I need to prove this to complete the big one.

Comment: That image is terribly blurry.  Do yourself a favor and learn to type with [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here.

Comment: To help your questions get a better reception, please provide some context. For example, you say that this is part of a larger exercise. Perhaps you could share with us what you're trying to accomplish, and the work you've done so far?

Comment: You have not specified what you mean by $i$ in this case., but if $i$ is meant to represent an arbitrary natural number including possibly $1$, then you should note that $e > \frac{1}{1!}$ and in fact $e > 1 \geq \frac{1}{n!}$ for all natural values of $n$.

Comment: As for the proposed identity in the body., assuming $i$ is an arbitrary natural, note: $\binom{n}{i}n^{-i}=\dfrac{n!}{i!(n-i)!n^i} = \dfrac{1}{i!}\cdot \dfrac{n\frac{i}{~}}{n^i}$ where $n\frac{i}{~}$ is notation for the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) $n\frac{i}{~} = \underbrace{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots (n-i+1)}_{i~\text{terms}}$.  The only missing step is to show $\dfrac{n\frac{i}{~}}{n^i}\leq 1$ which I expect you should be able to do.

Comment: @JMoravitz you should post as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. Now only I came to know "factorial of imaginary number".

Answer (score 0):

If we rewrite $$\binom{n}{i} n^{-i}=\frac{n!}{i! \,(n-i)!} n^{-i}\le \frac{1}{i!}$$ it is then necessary to prove that 
$$\frac{n!}{(n-i)!} n^{-i} \le1$$ At least for the case where $n$ is large and $i \ll n$, consider
$$a_n=\frac{n!}{(n-i)!} n^{-i}\implies \log(a_n)=\log(n!)-i \log(n)-\log((n-i)!)$$ and use Stirling approximation to get 
$$\log(a_n)=-\frac{i(i-1)}{2 n}-\frac{2 i^3-3 i^2+i}{12 n^2}+O\left(\frac 1 {n^3} \right)$$ Continue with Taylor
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=1-\frac{i(i-1)}{2 n}+\frac{i(i-1) (i-2)  (3 i-1)}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ If you limit the first expansion to $O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$, this would give $a_n=e^{-\frac{i(i-1)}{2 n}}$.